# Gaussian mean width of vector-valued function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, expected-value, stochastic-analysis

The Gaussian mean width of a subset $K\subseteq S^{n-1}_2$ is defined to be

$$\mathbb{E}\,\sup_{x\in K}\vert \big<g, x\big>\vert$$
where $g$ is a standard Gaussian random vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Suppose we are given a vectored valued function $v(t)\subseteq S^{n-1}_2 $ for $t\in [0,1]$ and it is Lipschitz in $t$. Is there any way to give an estimation on the gaussian width of $v(t)$?
Any reference are welcome!
Thank you in advance!